# isSet methods not generated using jaxb2-basics simplify plugin

Tags: java, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-basics

I have a schema with two elements within a `<xs:choice/>` block, as per the following fragment:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="POCD_MT000040.Component2">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="realmCode" type="CS" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="typeId" type="POCD_MT000040.InfrastructureRoot.typeId" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="templateId" type="II" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="nonXMLBody" type="POCD_MT000040.NonXMLBody"/>
            <xs:element name="structuredBody" type="POCD_MT000040.StructuredBody"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="NullFlavor" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="ActRelationshipHasComponent" use="optional" fixed="COMP"/>
    <xs:attribute name="contextConductionInd" type="bl" use="optional" fixed="true"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is part of the HL7/CDA specification schemas, by the way.

Well, I am using `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to generate the Java classes, with a touch of the `jaxb2-basics` plugin to simplify complex elements, like `nonXMLBody` and `structuredBody`. Let's say I have a bindings file with the following contents:

```xml
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:simplify="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/simplify"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc simplify"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:globalBindings
        typesafeEnumMaxMembers="1000"
        generateMixedExtensions="true"
        generateIsSetMethod="true"
        choiceContentProperty="true">

        <xjc:serializable uid="1" />
    </jxb:globalBindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/POCD_MT000040.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='POCD_MT000040.Component2']//xs:choice">
            <simplify:as-element-property />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The attributes are generated as expected:

```java
protected POCDMT000040NonXMLBody nonXMLBody;
protected POCDMT000040StructuredBody structuredBody;
```

However, although I am using `generateIsSetMethod="true"` in the global bindings, the methods `isSetNonXMLBody ( )` and `isSetStructuredBody ( )` are not being generated at all. The equivalent methods for the rest of the attributes are present, though, like `isSetTypeId ( )`.

Am I missing any option I should know of to generate these methods in the aforementioned elements?

Answer (score 0):

New issue created in jaxb-tools repository since jaxb2-basics has been merged there now : https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/issues/453

I've seen that property created by the simplify plugin are not wrapped like xjc properties and this wrap done is responsible of customizations like the isSet methods.

I'll update the answer with PR when provided and then with release when done if possible

**EDIT 21/11/2023** : PR created : https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/pull/455

**EDIT 24/11/2023** : PR merged, will be available in 4.0.1 release

**EDIT 06/02/2024** : 4.0.2 released

Comment: PR created : https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/pull/455